# A 3 level comparator

Tags: compare, vhdl

I want to make a comparator with some tolerance.

I have taken the difference between the two signals (hopefully)
Now I want to compare to a number (which will be decided later) and respectively forward signals of equal notequal and acceptable.

I have let the commented portion to help you understand my approach.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity threelvlcomp is
    port ( 
        input1    : in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        input2    : in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        outputeq  : out std_logic;
        outputneq : out std_logic
    );
end threelvlcomp;

architecture Behavioral of threelvlcomp is

signal temp : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal dif  : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
--CONSTANT limit      : INTEGER := 1;

begin

  dif <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(input1)) + std_logic_vector(unsigned(not(input2) + 1));
  --dif <= input1 + not(input2)+ "1";
  --dif <= input1 + not(input2) + "1"; 

    outputeq <= '1' when dif < '1'  else
            '0';
        outputneq <= '1' when dif > '1' else
            '0';


-- IF dif = "0000" THEN
-- outputeq   <= '1';
-- outputneq  <= '0';
-- outputacc  <= '0';
--ELSE IF dif /= '0' THEN
-- outputeq   <= '0';
-- outputneq  <= '1';
--outputacc  <= '0';
--ELSE IF dif <= "0.5"; 
-- outputeq   <= '0';
-- outputneq  <= '0';
-- outputacc  <= '1';
--ELSE
-- outputeq   <= '1';
-- outputneq  <= '1';
-- outputacc  <= '1';
--END IF; 

--  If(dif = 0) then outputeq <='1'; else outputeq <= '0';end if;
--  If(dif >= -0.5 and dif <= 0.5) then outputacc <='1'; else outputacc <= '0';end if;
--  If(dif /= 0) then outputneq <='1' else outputneq <= '0';end if;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: What error are you referring to? The only thing that immediately  jumps out is that you're mixing packages with conflicting declarations of unsigned - the Synopsys package std_logic_unsigned which will reference unsigned in Synopsys package std_logic_arith and IEEE package numeric_std. Straighten out your use clauses and at worst case you'll have to change the right hand side of the "<" and ">" operators (assuming -2008, just use package numeric_std_unsigned). It's not clear why you don't use an equality operator ("=").

Comment: What is your question? And what is the expected outcome? Please specify it using a mathematical equation.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code. But to me looks like it is what you are trying to do. It should at least help you with your signed/unsigned issue.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
--use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all; --do not use this it is confusing you

entity threelvlcomp is
    port ( 
        input1    : in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        input2    : in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        outputeq  : out std_logic;
        outputneq : out std_logic
    );
end threelvlcomp;

architecture Behavioral of threelvlcomp is

signal temp : unsigned(15 downto 0);
signal dif  : signed(16 downto 0);
--CONSTANT limit      : INTEGER := 1;

begin

-- you want a signed number here so we need to signed extend with a zero
  dif <= (signed('0'input1)) + (not signed('0'&input2)) + 1; 
  --dif <= input1 + not(input2)+ "1";
  --dif <= input1 + not(input2) + "1"; 

    outputeq <= '1' when dif < 1  else
            '0';
        outputneq <= '1' when dif > 1 else
            '0';
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Are you sure? `outputeq` can be determined by using the equality operator  (`=`). And `outputneq` is then just then negated value of `outputeq`.

Comment: no your right I'm not sure... It's a bit hard to tell what the user is wanting. But the way I interpreted it would make a 2 level / 3 states  comparator. The other way would just be a normal comparator (1 level / 2 sates).

Comment: I see now, that for a difference of 1, your design outputs `outputeq = '0'` as well as `outputeq = '0'`. ok, this would be a third state. You should indicate it in your answer because it could be easily overseen.